# image placement for IE bug fixes

Tags: css, html-lists

Hi ive got a menu that is like this:

```
<li id="selected"><a href="http://www."><p>FAQ'S</p></a></li>
```

I've managed to acheive the effect that i wanted in firefox but then i checked it in IE 7 and phwoooar...
It seems to be a width issue at the start i try to impeleent a width hack but then this upsets firefox:

```
#menu li#selected { padding: 0; margin:0; background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d; height: 35px;  }

#menu #selected a {background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat;height: 25px;}
#menu #selected p { padding: 0 10px; margin:4px; }
```

the other problem in ie is that the  image for the right seems to hang higher than the image on the left blah!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `<p>` - a block level element - inside `<a>` - an inline element.  It will be inconsistently rendered by the different browsers.

Try changing to

```
<li id="selected"><p><a href="http://www.">FAQ'S</a></p></li>
```

The image problem is because the height property does not apply to inline elements so your height:25px is being ignored. Move the image into place with padding.

```
#menu #selected a 
background:transparent url(nav-tab-right.gif) no-repeat scroll right bottom;
padding-bottom:16px;
}
```

Comment: -1: The `<p>` tag is non-semantic and not required to achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is an block level element. You cannot put it inside an inline element (`<a>`). What you can do is the following: Simply remove the `<p>`, and then use CSS to display the `<a>` tag as a block.

**HTML:**

```
<li id="selected"><a href="http://www.">FAQ'S</a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu li#selected {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d;
  height: 35px;
}

#menu #selected a {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px; /* Centers the text vertically */
  padding: 0 6px;    /* Gives 6px of horizontal padding to the text */
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will work in all browsers and doesn't clutter up your markup with useless elements.

---

## Hover Variation

Another advantage of using this method is that you can modify it slightly to allow for CSS rollover images that will be compatible with IE6 as such:

**HTML:**

```
<li id="selected"><a href="http://www."><span>FAQ'S<span></a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu li#selected {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  height: 35px;
}

#menu #selected a {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu #selected a span {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px; /* Centers the text vertically */
  padding: 0 6px;    /* Gives 6px of horizontal padding to the text */
  margin: 0;
}

/* Hovered, so let's change the colors and the images */
#menu #selected a:hover {
  background:url(nav-tab-left-hover.gif) bottom left no-repeat #902B27;
}

#menu #selected a:hover span {
  background:url(nav-tab-right-hover.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

Yes, it does work on IE6 and below (and above) since `a` is the only element for which IE6 supports the `:hover` pseudo-class. It is also the reason why this method requires adding an additional `<span>` tag as we cannot target the `<li>` with `:hover` in a way which IE6 understands.

<sub>I do recommend using [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) instead of separate images for the hover effect, but to keep this example as simple as possible, I will keep it as such.</sub>

For more information about CSS selectors support, see [*CSS - Contents and compatibility*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).