# css :after will not work

Tags: html, css

i have a css prop like stated

```
#menu li#selected { padding: 0 10px; margin:0; background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d; height: 35px; }
```

after the li i need to display the second part of the image nav-tab-right.gif

i try

```
#menu li#selected:after { background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat; }
```

but this returns inconclusive

Comment: Off-topic: The HTML standard says that ID's must be unique on a page, so '#menu li#selected# is identical to '#selected'.

Comment: @Colin: sometimes it is desirable to increase the CSS specificity of a particular rule.

Comment: @johnnnnnny: Please see my answer in your other question for a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159501/image-placement-for-ie-bug-fixes)'s HTML.

IE7 and below doesn't support the `:after` pseudo-element. Use something like this instead:

**HTML:**

```
<li id="selected"><a href="http://www.">FAQ'S</a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu li#selected {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d;
  height: 35px;
}

#menu #selected a {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px; /* Centers the text vertically */
  padding: 0 6px;    /* Gives 6px of horizontal padding to the text */
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will work in all browsers and doesn't rely on `:after` which IE7 and below doesn't support.

---

## Hover Variation

Another advantage of using this method is that you can modify it slightly to allow for CSS rollover images that will be compatible with IE6 as such:

**HTML:**

```
<li id="selected"><a href="http://www."><span>FAQ'S<span></a></li>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu li#selected {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  height: 35px;
}

#menu #selected a {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-left.gif) bottom left no-repeat #90288d;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu #selected a span {
  display: block;
  background:url(nav-tab-right.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px; /* Centers the text vertically */
  padding: 0 6px;    /* Gives 6px of horizontal padding to the text */
  margin: 0;
}

/* Hovered, so let's change the colors and the images */
#menu #selected a:hover {
  background:url(nav-tab-left-hover.gif) bottom left no-repeat #902B27;
}

#menu #selected a:hover span {
  background:url(nav-tab-right-hover.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

Yes, it does work on IE6 and below (and above) since `a` is the only element for which IE6 supports the `:hover` pseudo-class. It is also the reason why this method requires adding an additional `<span>` tag as we cannot target the `<li>` with `:hover` in a way which IE6 understands.

<sub>I do recommend using [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) instead of separate images for the hover effect, but to keep this example as simple as possible, I will keep it as such.</sub>

For more information about CSS selectors support, see [*CSS - Contents and compatibility*](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Answer (score 2):

Without a "content" property in the CSS, :after will do nothing. It selects for a pseudo-element representing the last child of the element is it applied to (a sort of virtual element which is a child of li#selected, in your case).

It's not a "placeholder" reference like regular expressions can do with start- and end-of-line; you actually have to provide a content property for it, which will be rendered but will not become part of the DOM tree. That content can be an empty string, but it must still be specified:

```
#menu li#selected:after
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red; 
}
```

That should give an idea of what's achievable.